# Checking for Deviation from Google Maps Route

Tags: java, android, google-maps, navigation, polyline

I am doing a project for school involving maps and navigation. What I have done till now is to  just use the Google Directions Web API to retrieve a JSON output and then parse it to get my directions. 
When navigating, a user may deviate from the path and here is where I want to do some rerouting. I think this might be a bit vague, but, how can I check for deviation from a certain route?

Comment: I do not know exactly how Google gives you the directions (hence the comment), but assuming you get a list of street names, you could get the directions from your current location to the target and then compare it with the initial set of directions (omitting the paths you have already gone through). If the two lists are the same (excluding paths you have already travelled), then you are still on the same path.

Comment: Its been a while since the question was asked, @Girish you have figured how to do that?